# What generation of the MrSID format is supported by ArcGIS 9.3?

Tags: raster, arcgis-9.3, file-formats

This is probably old news to some, but I just learned that MrSID (.sid) files have different 'generations' of file formats - so there are MrSID Generation 2, Generation 3, and Generation 4 files.  Does anyone know what generation of .sid is supported in ArcGIS 9.3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generation 3 is supported: [Data Formats Support in ArcGIS 9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Data_formats_supported_in_ArcGIS)

Generation 4 support is targeted for 10.1 according to ESRI forums.

Comment: Thanks!  I was on the same page earlier...strange that the same information isn't on the 'Supported raster dataset file formats' or 'About MrSID rasters' pages.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too, a bit misleading unless you look at both pages :(

Answer (score 1):

with your title and a bit of google i've got this link:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Data_formats_supported_in_ArcGIS

generation 3 is ok.

Generation 4 seems ok only with arcgis 10 (http://www.lizardtech.com/downloads/plugins.php)

Comment: Thanks...see my comment to the previous answer, I was close to finding it on my own, but there was different information on different pages.

Comment: Np, was a bit too long to check my facts and click send ^^