# Is there a simple way to detect what generation a MrSID file is?

Tags: raster, convert, mrsid

I just found out there are [a few types of MrSID files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13232/what-generation-of-the-mrsid-format-is-supported-by-arcgis-9-3) - generations MG2,MG3,MG4. As I have a user which uses Bentley Microstation V8 and apparently can see only some of the generations (and thus I need to convert between the different generations)- I wanted to know if there is a quick way to detect what generation a SID file is (I have AutoCAD 2007, ArcGIS 9.3.1)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ArcCatalog right click on the image and select Properties.  Look at the compression type, MG! (generation 1), MG2 (generation 2), MG3 (generation 3), and MG4 (generation 4).

Comment: As the answer is simple, I feel a bit stupid. But I thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

[gdalinfo](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) will also tell you the same information with a VERSION tag.